# Flutter-How to create otp code textfield like in the picture?

Tags: flutter

How to create otp code textfield like in the picture?
I tried the pinput and PinCodeTextField packages but I couldn't do it like in the picture. Can you help with this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

hi you can try with [pinput](https://pub.dev/packages/pinput). It's have very good pub points.

Answer (score 0):

Use [flutter_otp_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_otp_text_field) package.